# Deploy to AWS EKS using a service account

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, aws-eks

I need to deploy multiple (> 2 dozen) applications into distinct namespaces from GitLab. Unfortunately, Gitlab's old instance-wide Kubernetes integration has long been deprecated, and the new agent system requires setting up and configuring a separate agent per project which is infeasible at my scale.

My first attempt was to use Kubernetes `CertificateSigningRequest`s to create client certificates, but that failed because for some reason Kubernetes would not issue them despite being approved.

So, I tried deploying with `kubectl` directly - that works, but it seems like *all* guides I found simply say to use your existing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`/`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` credentials in the CI pipeline. This however is just plain bad because I don't want to leak my credentials all over Gitlab.

So, what is the current best practice to do deployments to an EKS cluster that at least somehow scale?